# Mobile redirect strategy

Tags: server, mobile, detection

Looking for help on deciding how to redirect users to a mobile optimized version of my site (m.mysite.com).

Looking at two methods:

1. Server configuration (.htaccess or even varnish)
2. Webapp (php)

The problem I see with #1 is with the "view full site" link on the mobile site.  If a user clicks that link and they go to mysite.com won't the server just redirect them back to m.mysite.com?

For #2 I could create a cookie that is checked in addition to the user agent.

Any suggestions/comments?  Is there a better way to "remember" if the user clicked "visit full site"?

Comment: You can check for cookies using mod_rewrite: look at `RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ...` and build your logic around. Each approach is possible. #2 is easier but required PHP to get involved which is more "expensive" in terms of CPU/resources than mod_rewrite (although it should be absolutely fine on any modern hardware **unless** it is under heavy load and limited in resources).

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue. I'm going with route number 2, because I want to people to be able to click the visit full site link on their mobile device. Did you figure out how to manage the cookie? Jim

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you use option #1 and set a cookie once they've been redirected. This will be effective in not just the current session of the user; but also future sessions.

Answer (score 1):

The only alternative to using a cookie is having your portal (index) redirect to m.mywebsite.com with the implicit understanding that m.mywebsite.com will never link to the plain pages at mywebsite.com.

Also take a look here:
http://csswizardry.com/2010/01/iphone-css-tips-for-building-iphone-websites/